# Python: adding element to tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

i have google searched for hours but still not able to find a solution.

```
x = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
y = 5.0
```

Is that possible to convert to the tuple format below?

```
(((1, 2), 5.0), (3, 4))
```

Edit: Solved. Thanks all.

Comment: it will be much better for us to understand why do you need this kind of transformation, is this single case or you have many `tuple`s that need to be modified?

Comment: It is just a single case and I am wondering anyway to create a tuple with the format above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable. But they do support indexing, so you can easily create a new one:

```
x = ((x[0], y), x[1])

# (((1, 2), 5.0), (3, 4))
```